# Why can't $(document).ready() be inside API call?

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

FYI Trial 1 does not work, but Trial 2 works.

I understand that getJSON is executes asynchronously, but I don't actually understand how it applies to the code I've written.

What can I learn about asynchronous execution from this?

Why do I have to separate the getJSON call into a function separate from ready()?

FOR TRIAL 2:
How can I write this code so I don't have to initialize functions inside of getJSON? If there isn't a way, how can I write this code to be more robust?

```
/*
//TRIAL 1
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("loaded");
  $.getJSON(url, function(json){
    var fahrenheit = true;
    getLocation(json);
    getTemperature(fahrenheit, json);
    $("#unit").on("click", function(){
      fahrenheit = !fahrenheit;
      getTemperature(fahrenheit, json);
    });
    getWeather(json);
  });
});

//Gets current weather conditions from current_observation
function getWeather(json){
  var currWeather = "";
  var iconURL = "";
  currWeather=json.current_observation.weather;
  iconURL=json.current_observation.icon_url;
  $("#icon").attr("src", iconURL);
  $("#weather").html(currWeather);      
};

//Gets current temperature from current_observation  
function getTemperature(fahrenheit, json){
  var currTemp = 0;
  if(fahrenheit){
    currTemp+=json.current_observation.temp_f;
    currTemp+="&#8457";
  } else{
    currTemp+=json.current_observation.temp_c;
    currTemp+="&#8451";
  }
  $("#temperature").html(currTemp);
};

//Gets city, state, country, zip, latitude, and longitude from location
function getLocation(json){
  var currLocation=["city", "state", "country", "zip", "lat", "lon"];
  var locationHTML = "";
  currLocation[0] = json.location.city;
  currLocation[1] = json.location.state;
  currLocation[2] = json.location.country_name;
  currLocation[3] = json.location.zip;
  currLocation[4] = json.location.lat;
  currLocation[5] = json.location.lon;
  locationHTML += currLocation[0]+", "+currLocation[1]+", "+currLocation[2]+" " +currLocation[3]+"<br>";
  locationHTML += "Latitude: "+currLocation[4]+"<br>Longitude: "+currLocation[5];
  $("#location").html(locationHTML);
};
*/

//TRIAL 2

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("loaded");
  dispWeather(); 
});

function dispWeather(){
  console.log("inside dispWeather");
  //Retrieve json from weather underground
  var url = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/19c5c96f0b140c0f/geolookup/conditions/q/autoip.json";
  $.getJSON(url, function(json){
    console.log("Got JSON");
    console.log(json);
    var fahrenheit = true;
    getLocation(json);
    getTemperature(fahrenheit, json);
    $("#unit").on("click", function(){
      fahrenheit = !fahrenheit;
      getTemperature(fahrenheit, json);
    });
    getWeather(json);

    //Gets current weather conditions from current_observation
    function getWeather(json){
      var currWeather = "";
      var iconURL = "";
      currWeather=json.current_observation.weather;
      iconURL=json.current_observation.icon_url;
      $("#icon").attr("src", iconURL);
      $("#weather").html(currWeather);      
    };

    //Gets current temperature from current_observation  
    function getTemperature(fahrenheit, json){
      var currTemp = 0;
      if(fahrenheit){
        currTemp+=json.current_observation.temp_f;
        currTemp+="&#8457";
      } else{
        currTemp+=json.current_observation.temp_c;
        currTemp+="&#8451";
      }
      $("#temperature").html(currTemp);
    };

    //Gets city, state, country, zip, latitude, and longitude from location
    function getLocation(json){
      var currLocation=["city", "state", "country", "zip", "lat", "lon"];
      var locationHTML = "";
      currLocation[0] = json.location.city;
      currLocation[1] = json.location.state;
      currLocation[2] = json.location.country_name;
      currLocation[3] = json.location.zip;
      currLocation[4] = json.location.lat;
      currLocation[5] = json.location.lon;
      locationHTML += currLocation[0]+", "+currLocation[1]+", "+currLocation[2]+" " +currLocation[3]+"<br>";
      locationHTML += "Latitude: "+currLocation[4]+"<br>Longitude: "+currLocation[5];
      $("#location").html(locationHTML);
    };
  })
};
```

Comment: Your first example does not include the value of `url`. Are you sure it was defined?

Answer (score 2):

`.ready()` [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

**What can I learn about asynchronous execution from this?**

Your learning that you don't know when the document is going to be `ready()` so we wait until the event completes before beginning execution on our application. You also learned that you have to wait for `$.getJSON` to fetch json `then` you process the data.

**Why do I have to separate the getJSON call into a function separate from ready()?**

As specified above `.ready()` is waiting for the DOM to be fully loaded, then we start the application. So when we are "ready" lets fetch the weather data. The document is only ready **one time** *when the DOM is fully loaded.*

**How can I write this code so I don't have to initialize functions inside of getJSON?**

Without you being specific, I'm assuming your problem here was with toggling the degrees between celsius and fahrenheit. After we load the weather you can store the data in a variable outside of the scope of the function, this way when you click to change the degrees you can pass in the same data without having to call the api again (although at this point the weather could have changed)

**how can I write this code to be more robust?**

I've included a JS Bin that alters your code. The biggest problem was bad naming conventions and not keeping things simple. Example `getWeather()` was not "getting weather" it was setting html from data we got from `$.getJSON` which was invoked in your `ready()` instead of breaking it out into another function we could call later on.

For the most part this is how the code reads now, clear function names help quickly see what this code is supposed to do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  renderWeather(); 
});

var state = {
    fahrenheit: true,
    data: {}
};

function renderWeather() {
  getWeatherJSON()
    .then(data => {
      state.data = data; 
      setWeatherHTML(data);
      setTemperatureHTML(data, state.fahrenheit);
      setLocationHTML(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

http://jsbin.com/cekite/edit?js,output

If we wanted to take this a step further we could create a WeatherAPI prototype concealing our html render functions and extend it with a WeatherUndergroudAPI prototype, this way if we ever change our weather service we should only have to implement a format function to marshall the data the way the WeatherAPI expects it to be in.

```
class WeatherAPI {
  constructor(opt) {
    ...
  }

  init() {
    ...
  }

  get() {
    ... feteches json from endpoint provided
  }

  renderWeather() {
    this.get()
      .then(this.formatter.bind(this))
      .then(this.setWeatherData.bind(this))
      .then(this.renderWeatherHTML.bind(this))
      .then(this.renderTemperatureHTML.bind(this))
      .then(this.renderLocationHTML.bind(this))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  formatter(data) {
    ...
  }

  setWeatherData(data) {
    ...
  }

  renderWeatherHTML() {
    ...
  }

  renderTemperatureHTML() {
    ...
  }

  renderLocationHTML() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Extending the WeatherAPI is then a matter of passing in a new endpoint to get data from. Or in this case overriding the WeatherAPI get method and returning static data.

```
class FakeWeatherAPI extends WeatherAPI {
  constructor(opt = {}) {
    super(opt);
  }

  get() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const data = {
        someReallyWeirdKeyForACity: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        country: 'US',
        lat: '37.77999878',
        lon: '122.41999817',
        f: '1000',
        c: '25',
        icon: 'http://www.nyan.cat/cats/zombie.gif',
        weather: 'Acid Rain'
      };

      resolve(data);
    });
  }

  formatter(data) {
    const formattedData = {
      city: data.someReallyWeirdKeyForACity,
      state: data.state,
      country: data.country,
      lat: data.lat,
      lon: data.lon,
      temperature: {
        fahrenheit: data.f,
        celsius: data.c
      },
      icon: data.icon,
      weather: data.weather
    };

    return formattedData;
  }
}
```

Our application init code then becomes.

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init(){
  const weatherAwesomeService = new FakeWeatherAPI();
  weatherAwesomeService.init();
};
```

Here is a working jsbin for they above

http://jsbin.com/sicofe/edit?js,output

Comment: This was so helpful, thank you very much for this feedback.